# Python - multiprocessing pool with functions with 2 inputs arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiprocessing, pool

I m trying to use multiprocess in order to decrease the time of calculation of functions whose depend of 2D arrays whose shape is 2000x2000. I have 2 inputs arrays for the function but with p.map it doesnt work...(with one it s ok). How can i do to enable that?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from numpy import *
import time
tic=time.clock()

Y=(arange(2000.))
X=(arange(2000.))
(xx,yy)=meshgrid(X,Y)


r = sqrt((xx)**2 + (yy)**2)

theta = (arctan2((yy),(xx)))

def f(theta,r):
  return 1.*r**(-3/2.)*cos(-3/2.*theta)

p = Pool(4)
print p.map(f, theta,r)
toc=time.clock()

print 'Temps=', toc-tic
```

and i get an error : "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: what version of python are you using? the answer can depend on it.

Comment: I m using ipython with python 2.7.8

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: @JulienSpronck: partial won't work in there without changing the function itself, since the first array that you pass to the function will be taken as a whole and not element by element.

Comment: @user3601754 I mean what Operating System?

Comment: Also, `map` is going to iterate over every item in the iterable you pass to it, and call `f` on each individual element. Is that actually what you want here? It looks like you want to pass both arrays in their entirety to the child process, and have `f` work on the whole array. If that's the case, `multiprocessing.Pool.map` won't help improve performance at all.

Comment: I actually don't think that multiprocessing will help at all for what you need to do with the arrays. numpy already does a good job with that.

Comment: For my real case, my function needs 2 seconds to be created...too long for me but the answer of Paulo.filip3 seems to work

Comment: The answer of Paulo works but i dont win time with...how can i get more time?

Comment: Dano sorry i m on ubuntu 14.10 Yep no better performance :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do solve that is to `zip` the input `arrays`

```
def f(values):
    return 1.*values[1]**(-3/2.)*cos(-3/2.*values[0])

p = Pool(4)
print p.map(f, zip(theta, r))
```

Comment: Thanks it works, just one little problem i get a list of array...  : "array([ -2.23942628e-05,  -2.23605957e-05,  -2.23268448e-05, ...,
          7.27439741e-06,   7.27185262e-06,   7.26930745e-06]), array..." How can i get an array with same shape as r or theta?

Comment: Oh, I see. You want the function to take the whole array instead of element by element. Then multiprocessing probably won't speed up much at all.
In that case do `print p.map(f, [[theta, r]])`

Comment: In that case you could also have done.

`from functools import partial; partial_f = partial(f, theta); res = p.map(partial_f, [r])`

Comment: thanks for your help! :) i will try that and i tell you if i won time! ;)